# Shell Script and user input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, while-loop

I'm writing a script, and plan on it being interactive. It's kind of like a scavenger hunt. The script basically greets the user and gives the user instructions on how to proceed.

The instructions involve a series of passwords (User input) that will reveal certain information based on which password is used. I plan on using a *break* on one of those passwords depending on the date.

I'll leave the code to be evaluated but I'm merely asking what is the right way to do so (What kind of loop, and a little help with the syntax.)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Welcome User"; sleep 2;
echo "Random greeting and intro to the game"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
        Yes) echo "Are you ready to play?"; break;;
        No) echo "Then get ready";;
    esac
done

echo "Please enter your first password"
```

There is a separate file using `:` as a field separator to be used with the game. I'm wondering what is the right way of looping the asking for a password and perform based on what is entered.

I'm looking for something simple that reads user input and based on whether it matches the other file performs a set of instructions (specific for each password), and once the last password is entered it finishes. I'm guessing while, read, if and or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a line of user input into the variable `$foo`, write:

```
IFS= read -r foo
```

(The `IFS=` tells it that there are no field separators, so it shouldn't discard any whitespace; the `-r` tells it that backslashes should be treated as literal backslashes.)

Your loop will probably be a "forever" loop, meaning that it loops until it encounters a `break` statement:

```
while true ; do
    ...
    if ... ; then
        ...
        break      # jump out of the loop
    fi
    ...
done
```

I have no idea what you mean by "whether [the user input] matches the other file" — it sounds like the other file is pretty complicated, with field separators and so on — but you will most likely want to read the other file into memory, storing its fields in appropriate variables:

```
IFS=: read -r field1 field2 field3 < the_other_file
```

Comment: I was thinking of something similar, I was winging it and wrote a portion of it using